# JavaScript: how do I save and apply my changes to a script loaded by a website

Tags: javascript

I am on a [podcast website](https://freakonomics.com/podcast/how-valuable-is-enthusiasm/) where they have a rewind button to rewind back to 10 seconds ago. I wanted to change it to 5 second ago.

I found the onClick handler in its source code and edited the code but it didn't work and it still rewinds to 10 seconds ago not 5 seconds ago.

I am pretty sure I edited the right code but it just didn't get saved and applied to the webpage. Am I missing something here?
[image]

Comment: You have to execute the updated click binding. You also need to remove the old click binding with `rewind.off("click");`

Comment: how do I execute the updated click binding?

Comment: Easiest would be to paste it into the console.

Comment: @Barmar sorry still not sure how to do that? paste what into the console exactly?

Comment: the edited `rewind.click(...)` call.

Comment: I think you can also just reload the page after editing the code.

Comment: @Barmar doesn't reload the page restore the script which reverts the changes?

Comment: No, when you edit the script and save it, Chrome knows that your edited version should be loaded instead.

Comment: When you're doing local editing you have to create a workspace, and the modified script is stored there.

Comment: Actually ... Hit CTRL+S, but don't reload.

Comment: CTRL+S doens't work either ...